# AVG function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server. I have a table that has an `int` column `HalfTimeAwayGoals` and I am trying to get the `AVG` with this code:

```
select 
    CAST(AVG(HalfTimeAwayGoals) as decimal(4,2)) 
from 
    testtable 
where 
    AwayTeam = 'TeamA'
```

I get as a result 0.00. But the correct result should be 0.55.

Do you have any idea what is going wrong ?

Comment: try `avg(cast(HalfTimeAwayGoals as decimal(4,2))`

Comment: If `HalfTimeAwayGoals` is of an integer type SQL Server will use integer math

Comment: Show us the sample data you're basing your expected result on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    AVG(CAST(HalfTimeAwayGoals as decimal(4,2))) 
from 
    testtable 
where 
    AwayTeam = 'TeamA'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field `HalfTimeAwayGoals` is an integer, then the `avg` function does an integer average.  That is, the result is 0 or 1, but cannot be in between.

The solution is to convert the value to a number.  I often do this just by multiplying by 1.0:

```
select CAST(AVG(HalfTimeAwayGoals * 1.0) as decimal(4, 2)) 
from testtable 
where AwayTeam = 'TeamA';
```

Note that if you do the conversion to a decimal *before* the average, the result will not necessary have a scale of 4 and a precision of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try dividing by 1.00 to convert the integer into decimal?

```
select
    AVG(HalfTimeAwayGoals/1.00) as average 
from
    testtable 
where
    AwayTeam = 'TeamA'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the /1.00 OR /1.0000 trick on various databases to do the job. Unfortunately, I don't have access MS-SQL to try it. The division of integer by 1.00 will change the integer to decimal.

```
SELECT AVG(integerfield/1.00) FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

cast(avg(cast(LoginCount as decimal(12,2))) as decimal(12,2))

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL

```
SELECT AVG(integerfield) FROM table
```

gives me 4 decimal points.

If I do

```
SELECT AVG(integerfield/1.00) FROM table
```

I get 8 decimal points.

Comment: Your answer is for MySQL; question is SQL Server and doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes I know. But I used to do the /1.00 OR /1.0000 trick on various databases to do the job. Unfortunately, I don't have access MS-SQL to try it. The division will change the integer to decimal.

Comment: Okay - put that in the answer and I can remove the down vote.